# How to Integration Dapper into Abp Framework

Tags: abp

I'm trying to integrate Dapper into the Abp application for reading data only.
Where should I put the repository and be able to access it from the Application layer? The documentation states that I have to pass in my DBContext
Many thanks
Zak

Answer (score 0):

You must put the repository interface in the domain layer and the implementation in the EntityFrameworkCore layer https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Dapper , in the implementation you inject the dbContext and do the query as shown shows in that example